# Does positive row scaling matrix don't change a sign of matrix's eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a positive diagonal matrix 
$$D = \textrm{diag}{[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \textrm{with } a_i\ge 0$$
Consider a diagonalizable matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that
it has an eigendecomposition
$$A = T^{-1} \Lambda T$$

Now, I only care about the whether the *sign of eigenvalue* of 
$A$ and $DA$ will differ.

I tested on some case, it looks to be true.

### Special case

Clearly, if the sign of eigenvalue already indicated by Gershgorin circle theorem (diagonal dominanted), then simply scaling it by any positive factor, won't change the **side** of circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question, as put, has no answer since eigenvalues can be complex. For example, $$\begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\2&2\end{pmatrix},\qquad\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\2&2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4& -2 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ have eigenvalues $2\pm i\sqrt2$ and $1,1$ respectively.

Moreover, if $a_i=0$ then the signs can obviously change. But if you allow only real eigenvalues and $a_i>0$, the answer is that the sign *can* still change in special cases. For example,

$$\begin{pmatrix}20&-31\\20&-30\end{pmatrix},\qquad\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}20&-31\\20&-30\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}40 & -62 \\
 10 & -15\end{pmatrix}$$ have eigenvalues $-5\pm\sqrt5=-5\pm2.2$ and $(25\pm\sqrt{545})/2=12.5\pm11.7$ respectively.